# JWT Authentication by role claims in ASP.NET core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

How I can authenticate user by claims, which contains in user roles?

In `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => {
                options.AddPolicy("CanEdit", policy => policy.RequireClaim("CanEdit"));    
});
```

And in login controller I have:

```
    private async ValueTask<JwtSecurityToken> GetJwtSecurityToken(ApplicationUser user){
        //var totalClaims = new List<Claim>();
        //var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
        //foreach (var role in userRoles) {
        //    var roleClaims = await _roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(await _roleManager.Roles.SingleAsync(r => r.Name.Equals(role)));
        //    totalClaims.AddRange(roleClaims);
        //}
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.Email)
        };
        return new JwtSecurityToken(
            _configuration["Token:Issuer"],
            _configuration["Token:Audience"],
            //totalClaims,
            claims
            expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(12),
            signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(
                new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Token:Key"])),
                SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
        );
    }
```

Method `policy.RequireClaim` search claims in token, not in role.

When I uncomment the lines, it works.
Is this a good solution?

Answer (score 10):

To add roles to claims, you'll need use claim type Role, like so:

```
var rolesList = new List<string>
    {
     "Admin",
     "SuperUser",
     "Etc..."
    };


foreach (var role in rolesList)
    {
     claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
    }
```

NB:- when creating token ensure claims are added.

```
var Token = new JwtSecurityToken(
    issuer: "localhost",
    audience: "localhost",
    expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10),
    claims:claims //claims added to token here!
    signingCredentials: Creds);
    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(Token);
    }
```

That's it, now you can test if the token contains the role "Admin" via the Authorize attribute.

```
   [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
```

NB:- To test against multiple roles (the token contains the claim "Admin" or "SuperUser")

```
  [Authorize(Roles="Admin","SuperUser")]
```

EDIT as pointed out by @gentiane below

```
  [Authorize(Roles="Admin,SuperUser")]
```

Comment: Could you have a look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53194947/configuring-identity-server-to-use-asp-net-identity-roles?noredirect=1#comment93278923_53194947 ?

Comment: There is a little typo, it is `[Authorize(Roles="Admin,SuperUser")]`